# Why space in input checkValidity is true?

Tags: html

```
<input type="text" required>

$('input').blur(function () {
    console.log($('input')[0].checkValidity());
});
```

When I typed a space, the console gives a `true`. This is very confuse...

Comment: because the space is character with code ASCII 30 , then absolutely it will return true ( ' ' != null  )

Comment: You can check [The required attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-required-attribute) section.

Comment: @bfahmi, this is what I want, thank you!

Comment: @user5809498; you are welcome :) please mark it the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attibute `required` checks only if there is any character in input (also whitespaces).

If you want to check against blanks you could use `pattern`.

```
<input type="text" pattern="\S+" required>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the html5 pattern

i give you an example but you can put what you want

```js
$('input').blur(function () {
    console.log($('input')[0].checkValidity());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- this pattern don't allow to put a space in th input-->
<input type="text" pattern="^((?!\s).)*$" required>
```

Comment: I know how to fix it, what I want to know is why.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.